# Include unavailable objects in filtering

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS. I want to include all the unavailable objects of `Value` while filtering. In the code below, I am applying the condition `Value >= 4 && Value < 6`. I want `(Value >= 4 && Value < 6) || unavailable values of` **Value**`

```js
var Annual = [{"Date":1998,"Value":6.5,"GDPAnn":9062800},{"Date":1999,"GDPAnn":9631200},{"Date":2000,"Value":4.1,"GDPAnn":10251000},{"Date":2001,"GDPAnn":10581900}]

result = Annual.filter(function(v) { return v.Value >= 4 && v.Value < 6; })

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What about `|| typeof v.Value === 'undefined'`? There are many ways to check the existence of a property

Comment: `(v.Value >= 4 && v.Value < 6) || !v.value)` ??

Comment: If you only want to check if the object has the property value (regardless of it's actual value) you could use `"value" in object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `!v.Value` condition to your boolean expression

```js
var Annual = [{"Date":1998,"Value":6.5,"GDPAnn":9062800},{"Date":1999,"GDPAnn":9631200},{"Date":2000,"Value":4.1,"GDPAnn":10251000},{"Date":2001,"GDPAnn":10581900}]

result = Annual.filter(function(v) { return (v.Value >= 4 && v.Value < 6) || !v.Value; })

console.log(result);
```

Edit:

Like said in a comment below, in a case that you would not to consider that any falsy value is invalid (like zero, empty string, etc), you might prefer using the `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` method.

```js
const Annual = [{"Date":1998,"Value":6.5,"GDPAnn":9062800},{"Date":1999,"GDPAnn":9631200},{"Date":2000,"Value":4.1,"GDPAnn":10251000},{"Date":2001,"GDPAnn":10581900}]

const result = Annual.filter(function(v) { 
    return (v.Value >= 4 && v.Value < 6) || !v.hasOwnProperty("Value"); 
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You might want to include that:
If you don't consider `0` an invalid value you could do `|| (v.Value !== 0 && !v.Value)`

Comment: I added something in this way with hasOwnProperty, but it looks like we are a bunch of duplicated answers here 

Answer (score 0):

`typeof` check if value undefined make the job too.

```js
const Annual = [{"Date":1998,"Value":6.5,"GDPAnn":9062800},{"Date":1999,"GDPAnn":9631200},{"Date":2000,"Value":4.1,"GDPAnn":10251000},{"Date":2001,"GDPAnn":10581900}]

result = Annual.filter((v) => v.Value >= 4 && v.Value < 6 || typeof v.Value === "undefined");

console.log('res',result);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `hasOwnProperty` method to check if the object has a property called `Value` and negate it.

```js
var Annual = [{"Date":1998,"Value":6.5,"GDPAnn":9062800},{"Date":1999,"GDPAnn":9631200},{"Date":2000,"Value":4.1,"GDPAnn":10251000},{"Date":2001,"GDPAnn":10581900}]

result = Annual.filter(function(v) { return (v.Value >= 4 && v.Value < 6) || !v.hasOwnProperty('Value') })

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in different ways.

- If falsy value which is `0` is not a valid one then you can use `!v.value` along with the `v.Value >= 4 && v.Value < 6`

```js
const Annual = [{"Date":1998,"Value":6.5,"GDPAnn":9062800},{"Date":1999,"GDPAnn":9631200},{"Date":2000,"Value":4.1,"GDPAnn":10251000},{"Date":2001,"GDPAnn":10581900}]

const result = Annual.filter(v => (v.Value >= 4 && v.Value < 6) || !v.Value)

console.log(result);
```

- You can use `Object.hasOwnProperty()` method to check if property exist or not.

```js
const Annual = [{"Date":1998,"Value":6.5,"GDPAnn":9062800},{"Date":1999,"GDPAnn":9631200},{"Date":2000,"Value":4.1,"GDPAnn":10251000},{"Date":2001,"GDPAnn":10581900}]

const result = Annual.filter(v => (v.Value >= 4 && v.Value < 6) || !v.hasOwnProperty('Value'))

console.log(result);
```